# UIImagePickerController: Detecting Camera button (shutter) pressed

Tags: iphone, image, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, nsnotification

I would like to call a method that takes an NSNotification immediately after the user presses the camera shutter (i.e when the "Preview" tab bar has the buttons "Retake" and "Use").

I can't use the didFinishPickingImage method because at this time the user has already pressed the "Use" button.

I have already implemented this by cameraOverlayView property of UIImagePickerController(see comments), but I wonder whether there are quicker ways of 'observing' this action.

Any ideas?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?  could you use custom picture taking controls and bypass the standard use/retake controls?

Comment: I want to display an alert after the user takes the picture. I am trying to avoid using Custom Views to raise the chances of the app being accepted in the App Store.

Comment: As a credit to David who mentioned it, because I was running out of time in my project, this was my way out. So I settled for the cameraOverlay feature of SDK 3.1+ to solve this. 
Ref: 
1. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView

2. http://mobile-augmented-reality.blogspot.com/2010/01/good-tutorial-about-using.html. 
It is legit so no worries about Apple. But was time consuming than a simple observer method would do.

Answer (score 4):

To learn about camera button press event, you can fire a `NSNotification` for it.

```
// Add observer for when camera button is pressed
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: @selector(yourFunctionToPerform), name: "_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem", object: nil)
```

Also add the following method to the `ViewController` where you are creating `ImagePickerViewController`:

```
-(void) yourFunctionToPerform{

    //Do what you want to do on Camera button tap event

}
```

I was searching for this problem too, the key/name for the event is really obscure.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a genius! Easy and not workarounded solution at all! I definitelly like that approach :)

Answer (score -2):

You CAN display it AFTER they choose the image.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
        //Display the UIAlertView
    [alertView show];
        //Just never use the image
}
```

If you don't want to use the image you really don't have to

Comment: Thanks Jaba. But the idea really is that I want to catch the user while he can still quickly "Retake" the picture. Reason: User friendliness.