# iPhone SDK - How to disable the picture preview in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, photo, preview

Is there any way to disable the image preview after taking a picture with the UIImagePickerController? I want to dismiss the ImagePicker as soon as the user pressed the shutter release button.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197707/uiimagepickercontroller-detecting-camera-button-shutter-pressed)

My solution was to create a customized view on top of the default UIImagePickerControllerView.

I downloaded the example [Augmented Reality](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/508075/augmented_reality/AugmentedRealitySample.zip)

Then you can use the OverlayView.m and OverlayView.h by adding them to your project:
I made the custom picker toolbar, picker and overlayView global so that I can access them anywhere in the project.

In your ViewController.h

```
@class OverlayView;

@interface ViewController //bla bla...
{
UIImagePickerController * picker;
UIToolbar *toolBar;
OverlayView *overlayView; 
}
```

I created the controls of the toolbar a camera button and the cancel button

```
// toolbar - handy if you want to be able to exit from the image picker...
            toolBar=[[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480-55, 320, 55)] autorelease];
            toolBar.barStyle =  UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
            NSArray *items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel  target:self action:@selector(cancelPicture)] autorelease],
                            [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace  target:nil action:nil] autorelease],
                            [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera  target:self action:@selector(shootPicture)] autorelease],
                            [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace  target:nil action:nil] autorelease],
                            [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace  target:nil action:nil] autorelease],
                            nil];
            [toolBar setItems:items];

            // create the overlay view
            overlayView=[[[OverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480-44)] autorelease];
            // important - it needs to be transparent so the camera preview shows through!
            overlayView.opaque=NO;
            overlayView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

                    // parent view for our overlay
        UIView *parentView=[[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 480)] autorelease];
        [parentView addSubview:overlayView];
        [parentView addSubview:toolBar];

        // configure the image picker with our overlay view
        picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        // hide the camera controls
        picker.showsCameraControls=NO;
        picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

The cancel method

```
- (IBAction)cancel {
    // Don't pass current value to the edited object, just pop.
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The (shootPictureMethod):

```
-(void) shootPicture {

    [picker takePicture];

}
```

To exit without showing preview just dismiss the view after taking the picture in the didFinishPickingImage method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo 
{
//do whatever

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: In this example, isn't the button that snaps picture small?

Comment: @erastusnjuki I'm facing an issue in case of iPad. The issue is that while repositioning the toolBar from Portrait-to-Landscape and vice-versa the toolBar repositioning effect is clearly visible (i.e. toolBar is being moved from one position to another in small time-frame). How to fix this issue?

Comment: didFinishPickingImage is deprecated now I think

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the swift version:

```
                /// toolbar - handy if you want to be able to exit from the image picker...
            toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 480 - 55, width: 320, height: 55))
            toolBar?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
            
            let items = [
                UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self,
                                action:#selector(cancelPicture)),
                UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
                UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .camera, target: self,
                                action:#selector(shootPicture))
            ]
            
            toolBar?.items = items

            // create the overlay view
            let overlayView = OverlayView()
            overlayView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480 - 44)

            // important - it needs to be transparent so the camera preview shows through!
            overlayView.view.isOpaque = false

            picker.view.addSubview(overlayView.view)
            picker.view.addSubview(toolBar!)
            

            // hide the camera controls
            picker.showsCameraControls = false
            picker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView.view
            
            toolBar?.snp.makeConstraints{(make) ->  Void in
                make.width.equalTo(180)
                make.height.equalTo(50)
                make.top.equalTo(picker.view.snp.bottom).offset(-200)
                make.centerX.equalTo(picker.view.snp.centerX)
            }
```