# How to remove the "Preview" view after I take a picture in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, photo, preview

I'm using UIImagePickerController to take pictures. It's quite simple. But I have a problem: There is always a "Preview" view to let me "Retake" or "Use". Which is not what I want. I want to save my pictures straight away inside my photo albums.

I've found some articles about this problem, here are some of them:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300616/iphone-sdk-how-to-disable-the-picture-preview-in-uiimagepickercontroller/8774908#8774908)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300616/iphone-sdk-how-to-disable-the-picture-preview-in-uiimagepickercontroller/8774908#8774908)

Basically they are using a OverlayView which can solve the problem. But there is new problem. I can't use volume up key to take pictures anymore after I use OverlayView. Are there another solution to disable the stupid "Preview" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access the camera directly and not use UIImagePickerController at all.

Check out the following classes:
AVCaptureSession
AVCaptureDevice
AVCaptureDeviceInput
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

With these classes you can display your own camera preview and save the image when button is pressed.
There is example here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html

Comment: I've tried these but none of them work for me. I think Apple intend to do that.Either allow you to adjust the volume by showing the preview page or doesn't allow you to adjust the volume at all.