# UIImagePickerController avoiding the use/retry view after picture taken without disabling other controls

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I'd like to avoid the use/retry view after the picture is taken without disabling the default Apple camera controls that let me take the picture.

Doing this:

```
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

Causes ALL the camera controls to disappear. Is there any other method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no proper way to do this provided by Apple. So here are you options:

1. showCameraControls = NO and adding your own controls.
2. go hardcore and use AVFoundation - but again you'll need your own controls - probably not what you're looking to do but if you're interested I have a sample app of this here:

https://github.com/Shein/CameraFeedUnderlay

3. Hack around it - place YOUR OWN button on top of camera control play button and override the action to take the picture as you would without camera controls and directly dismiss the UIImagePickerController.

There's a sort-of example of this solution here:

[iPhone SDK - How to disable the picture preview in UIImagePickerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300616/iphone-sdk-how-to-disable-the-picture-preview-in-uiimagepickercontroller)

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this helps. You can use `imagePicker.showsCameraControls = YES;` in collaboration with `NSNotificationCenter` listening to @"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem" and @"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidRejectItem".

When entering the @"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem" state, you could then dismiss the `UIImagePickerController`.

I had a similar problem, hiding a overlay when entering the preview view. I could [solve the problem with this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23899448/1933185).

Comment: How do you get the uiimage using this approach ?

Comment: @Softlion check the link

Comment: Yeah i found the easy way

Comment: I'm just trying to skip the use photo/ retry and I can't get the shooted photo, coz func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo ...) not getting triggered with a such approach and using of @_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem" notification.

Answer (score 4):

You can customize an image picker controller to manage user interactions yourself. To do this, provide an overlay view containing the controls you want to display, and use the methods described in “Capturing Still Images or Movies.” You can display your custom overlay view in addition to, or instead of, the default controls. Custom overlay views for the UIImagePickerController class are available in iOS 3.1 and later by way of the [cameraOverlayView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) property. For a code example, see the [PhotoPicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196) sample code project.

from this you can create your own customCameraView to show your own controls that you need to show