# Can I prevent the confirmation screen in the image picker from appearing?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

I reach a camera class in ios. The ADMSImageUploader.h is as follows

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface ADMSImageUploader : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property BOOL newMedia;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *previewImage;

- (IBAction)returnButtonClicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)retakeButtonClicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)uploadButtonClicked:(id)sender;


-(void)openCamera:(NSString *)dealerId : (NSString *)inventoryId;

@end
```

the code in the .m file is as follows. there is a function below which opens the camera

```
-(void)useCamera{
     if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    _newMedia = YES;
}
```

}

here is the image of the camera

[image: camera image]

i would like to prevent the screen below from appearing and display the captured image in to image view

[image: prevent this screen from appearing]

thank you for the help.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300616/iphone-sdk-how-to-disable-the-picture-preview-in-uiimagepickercontroller) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage* Image = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [self previewImageOverlayView:Image];    
}

-(void)previewImageOverlayView :(UIImage *)captureImage
{
    CGRect deviceRect= [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    float screenHeight=deviceRect.size.height;

    UIView *previewImageOveraLayView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:deviceRect];
    [previewImageOveraLayView setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];

    UIImageView *previewImage=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [previewImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [previewImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,screenHeight-60)];
    [previewImage setImage:captureImage];
    [previewImageOveraLayView addSubview:previewImage];

    UIButton *retakeBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [retakeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(useOrRetakeBtnPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [retakeBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [retakeBtn setTitle:@"Retake" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [retakeBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [retakeBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0,screenHeight-60,160,60)];
    [previewImageOveraLayView addSubview:retakeBtn];


    UIButton *useBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [useBtn setTag:2000];
    [useBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(useOrRetakeBtnPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [useBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [useBtn setTitle:@"Use" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [useBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [useBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(160,screenHeight-60,160,60)];
    [previewImageOveraLayView addSubview:useBtn];


    [imagePicker.view addSubview:previewImageOveraLayView];
}
-(IBAction)useOrRetakeBtnPress:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [sender.superview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AVCapturSession instead of UIImagePickerController. You can play with it and use it as you want.

For more details on this Visit [Apple sample code for this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html)