# iOS - make UIImagePickerController keep shooting images(skip preview) just like Camera app

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to capture as many images as I need without going to the preview view that provides cancel and retake options. It is what Camera app has been doing. Is that possible to do with UIImagePickerController or I have to implement my own camera solutions?

Cheers

Comment: You can use imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO; it will disable the controls.

Comment: Hey BKjadav, I want to keep the default controls but just need to skip the preview step. I could listen to "_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem" notification and reload image picker there. Wondering if any other/better way to do it.

Comment: Look out this link... may it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300616/iphone-sdk-how-to-disable-the-picture-preview-in-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: Yeah, I saw that when I tried to google a solution. That suggestion used custom overlay. Don't want to make it complicated for now. I will just use "_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem" notification to reload the view for the time being. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: @user744641 did you find a solution?