# Possible to get notification from camera when my app is running in the background?

Tags: ios

I'm building an iOS mobile app that needs to be notified whenever the user takes a new picture with the camera of the iPhone (with the phone's default camera app).

I tried to google it, but I couldn't find out if this is possible:

1. my app runs in the background
2. user takes a new picture with the camera (outside of my app, using the phone's default camera app)
3. my app gets notified by NotificationCenter and I can save the picture the user has just taken right after the user took the picture

Swift or Objective-C solution would be good as well. Any help is appreciated, even a yes or no answer (whether it's possible or not)

Comment: you can get photos when your open your app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877195/swift-3-load-photos-from-photos-camera-roll-without-using-uiimagepickercontroll

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need a notification when the user uses the camera

Comment: You won't get any notification like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any possibilities, as of now.
I don't know why, but my guess would be that for security reasons Apple won't let camera run in the background at all.

Other alternatives may include:

1. Using `UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem` to listen to camera button press event, [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197707/uiimagepickercontroller-detecting-camera-button-shutter-pressed).
2. As suggested in your question comments by @dharmesh, you can obtain your photos, when the user opens your app.

**EDIT**

You can observe the [changes made in the photo library](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrarychangeobserver) to track if any changes (here, addition) of photos are done.

Comment: Thank you :) In the link from the 1st part of your answer: doesn't it only work when I open the camera app from my app? Does it work if the camera app is opened separately from my app (my app is running in the background)?

Comment: No, I don't think it'll work that way. In fact, like I  said, I don't think there could be a way to even operate camera from the background, but I'd love to know if there is a way. :)

Comment: The camera would run normally, not just in the background. My app would run in the background and detect that there was a picture taken. Is it possible with the 1st answer you gave?

Comment: Updated my answer.